# How to move home partition to different start point?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have tried moving/resizing partitions before and have ended up on many occasions breaking the installation (somehow). I do android ROM building, so I need to resize my home partition, but my layout is windows-linux home partition-linux / partition-swap, so I need to resize the windows partition, then grow the home partition towards the start of the disk. Will this break its mount? And if so how could I preemptively fix that?

Comment: "sI do android ROM building so I need to resize my home partition" explain this cuz I see no relation? -I- would symlink a dir called "android" in /home/$USER/ to an another location. No need to mess with /home/ and you can use NTFS for that location. I would keep / /home swap and C: as small as possible and create a big partition for all your personal stuff.

Comment: the android source takes up a good 50gb for the latest one, and a full build can take over 100

Comment: Ah that is a lot more than I expected :-D Mind you: if you use gparted to do the resizing of the partitions it should not break your mounts. Of course a backup is adviced ;)

Comment: You almost certainly need to resize in steps reduce a partition -> apply changes -> make a partition larger -> apply changes.